# Jagged Array of 2d arrays error

Tags: c#, jagged-arrays

I try to write an int-Array, but

why I can't write:

```
int[][,] JaggedInt = new int[5][5,5];
```

and how can I write a similar Jagged int as above.

Comment: If you know ahead of time that all of your arrays will have 5 elements, then perhaps you don't need a jagged array? `new int[5,5,5]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a jagged array you need to initialize each array separately:

```
int[][,] JaggedInt = new int[5][,];
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    JaggedInt[i] = new int[5,5];
```

if it were a 3-dimensional array instead of a jagged array you could do:

```
int[,,] JaggedInt = new int[5,5,5];
```

Answer (score 2):

From [`Jagged Arrays (C# Programming Guide)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx)

> Before you can use a jagged array, its elements must be initialized.

`[5][5,5]` means your jagged array has `5` array which all they are two-dimensional and their dimensions are `5` and `5`.